# how to use the fuzzy KNN in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, classification

This is my knn part ..the line code of fuzzy knn is not working a little help will be useful..noting that its a gender classification code  and the knn value is k=1.

```
sample= coefficent';

training=X ;
group = Y;

class = fknnclassify(X,2,Y, [0 1],1,info,fuzzy);
if class==1
    x='Male';
else % the female label is  0 %
    x='Female';
end
```

Comment: Do you mean `knnclassify`? I don't find `fknnclassify`.

Comment: please make a minimal executable block of code. E.g., define X,Y and make a code that runs (even if it gives the wrong output, give us a starting point...)

Comment: Also, assume we don't know what knn is.  Write your question like we might not be looking over your shoulder at the homework assignment...